# SVN: keep a file out of sync

Tags: svn

Let's say that under SVN directory there's a config file. However, due to some reasons, my machine would need a different config than the one in the trunk, say some proxy settings.

But, every time I update the directory, the config file will be overriden to the directory's default config file and/or will cause a conflict.

My question is how can I set this file to be out of sync from the trunk so that neither update will overwrite my local file nor commit will overwrite trunk's version.

(svn ignore will not be an option, we do need this config file in the directory, since otherwise other users will have to write one their own.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience, how I manage SVN update is only update the necessary files. For example the files in source or view folders, and unless its necessary I will update the library folders or config folders(Where I store all configurations or properties file.

Of course this can only be done if your project is well structured.